# Magento 2: update an existing backend menu item

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.0, adminmenu

Let's say there's a module that declares a custom admin menu item via `menu.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::test" title="Test" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="100" parent="Magento_Backend::content" resource="Vendor_Module::test" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

How to update (let's say change the label) this menu item via another module's `menu.xml` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems like the `menu.xml` handles the following actions:

- add
- remove
- update

Thus you can something like this to update an existing menu item:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <update id="Vendor_Module::test" title="Updated Test" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="100" parent="Magento_Backend::content" resource="Vendor_Module::test" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Sample: <update id="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo" title="Credit Memos" translate="title" module="Magento_Sales" sortOrder="30" parent="VendorName_ModuleName::item" action="sales/creditmemo" resource="Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo"/> Thanks for the answer @Raphael

Answer (score 2):

create layout file in your module at app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml

In this file update menu by its id.

Let say if you want to change product menu label then your code should be,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <update id="Magento_Catalog::catalog_products" title="My Products"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Here is Reference Screenshots

Before :https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1kTE.png & After :https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOTUe.png

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the menu.xml handles the following actions:

add
remove
update
Thus you can something like this to update an existing menu Customer Title change:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <update id="Magento_Customer::customer" title="Updated Test" />
    </menu>
</config>
```