# Store menu module or file location

Tags: magento2

I want to edit **menu.xml** inside the store's menu on the admin dashboard, is that possible? because I can't find any module named **stores** inside **app/code/** directory

[image]

Comment: if module was installed using composer, it can be found in vendor folder..

Comment: are you looking for Amasty fee module ?

Comment: @Pawan can u help me to give the exact route for this Stores directory?

Comment: i don't know about this "Amasty fee module", is that still related to Stores menu inside this admin page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I hope you are aware of Admin Menu. If not, please go through the basics. References: [Mageplaza article](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-menu-magento-2.html), [Bss commerce article](https://bsscommerce.com/blog/create-admin-menu-in-magento-2/), [Magefan article](https://magefan.com/blog/add-new-element-to-magento-2-admin-menu) and probably you can find more this on Google.
2. In general, module will be found on two places. One is inside **Vendor** and another one is **app/code**. In vendor, core magento module and the modules insalled via composer will be available. In app/code, customized module or any new feature modules will be available which we known as 3rd party module. Please note the modules installed via composer also known as 3rd party module. Reference: [Module Overview](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_intro.html)
3. Please check **Magento_Backend** vendor in which you can see **menu.xml** in path **vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml**. This is where the whole magento menu begins where you can see **Magento_Backend::stores** which is a store menu.[image]
4. If you want to add **new menu/submenu** or **update an existing menu** to place somewhere else, the use of **parent** decides where it should be done. I suggest always refer core functionalities as it will be helpful to stick with Magento. If you want to add new section in stores menu, refer the existing menu such as **Inventory** is added in spearate module by **/vendor/magento/module-inventory-admin-ui/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml** (Reference: [Update an existing menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114433/magento-2-update-an-existing-backend-menu-item))
   [image]